# How do I move the pointer between laptop screen and external monitor?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

I recently began using an external monitor, along with my macbook screen, to hold multiple windows.

I am looking for a way to move the pointer between each display. I want to use my mouse as little as possible due to Carpal Tunnel.

Ideally I would toggle between display and center the pointer with a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'd know is to adjust you mouse speed to go faster. Unless you write some system program that controls mouse position.